# HTTP Status 404 Tomcat Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat

I'm going to be honest, never used this before, I'm simply trying to install it correctly. I'm running windows 7 and I have jre 6 and 7. I go to system properties, environment variables and enter in a new system variable : JRE_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7. I run startup.bat and go to localhost:8080/" and I get

```
HTTP Status 404 - /%E2%80%9D

type Status report

message /%E2%80%9D

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Help would be absolutely awesome.

Comment: trying to install tomcat 7 by the way

Comment: did you applied the steps down there and fix your problem?

Comment: Try and validate your answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This a problem with tomcat and the `catalina config files`:

**what you have to do is simply:**

- right click on the `server tomcat` in `eclipse`
- click on properties
- click switch location a little server will appear on the left side in the navigation view
- double click on it after you have launched your server
- Then select use Tomcat installation and save

**this will solve that common `404` problem.**

Answer (score 1):

> HTTP Status 404 - /%E2%80%9D

What is `/%E2%80%9D` here ? First try to run it at root `'/'`

To setup tomcat you need to follow these steps

1. Extract tomcat in some directory. Make sure you have read/write privileges on this directory
2. Make sure that java is installed on the system. (run *java -version* on the console and you should get the version of java on your system).
3. Run *startup.bat* , the command prompt will open up displaying all the logs stating a clean startup in XXseconds
4. Next open the URL in the browser `http://localhost:8080/` and you should see the default page of Tomcat7 loaded up.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue in my app.And I resolved it.I changed server.xml  under Server folder.I should see  tag in server.xml

Comment: Hi philip 404 error is common error.Anbody cant say certain cause of this error.But in my project I resolved it change  <Context path=" tag ..